# Return an element of a for-loop outside the for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop

How can I do to  return an element of a for-loop?

```
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
//we only neeed one good element of the list
    String find(){
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            if (list.get(i).isGood()) {
                return list.get(i);
            }
        }
   return list.get(i); //doesn't work obviously, but how to make it work?
}
```

It doesn't compile because there is no return statement. I would like to return list.get(i).

Comment: If you have a return statement, you don't need the break statement.

Comment: Why break? The return statement ends the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `break` after a `return` call is unnecessary, since the method is exited after the `return` statement. Therefore the `break` statement has no chance of ever being executed which is why this code doesn't compile.

Furthermore you need a `return` or `throw` statement after the loop in case no value is returned form the loop, e.g.:

```
String find(){
   for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        if (list.get(i).isGood()) {
            return list.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It is not unnecessary. It is an error, unreachable code statement.

Comment: Okay i understand that break is unecessary, but i don't want to return null or else it will be too easy, with null it will compile but it's not what i want

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to `break` as you have called `return`. It exits the method from the line where `return` is called. So you don't have to think to break the loop.

Learn more about [return](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).

Answer (score 0):

When a `return` instruction is reached the code **exit immediately** from the current function, so any following line is not accepted because will never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

`break;` call is unreachable code statement.
Any code brunch should have return statement.
With Stream API:

```
String find() {
    return list.stream()
               .filter(Clazz::isGood)
               .findFirst()
               .get();
}
```